# If $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^1(\mathbb{R})$ then $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following:

> If $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^1(\mathbb{R})$ then $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$

I figured that if I can show that $f$ is bounded by some $M$, then I can write:

For all $N \in \mathbb{N}$: $$ \int_{-N}^N|f(x)|^2\leq M \int_{-N}^N|f(x)| $$ and then take $N \to \infty$ and obtain the result.

To show $f$ must be bounded, I prove by contradiction:
Suppose it is not. Then for every $M>0$ there is an $x_M$ such that $|f(x)|>M$. Moreover, since $f \in C$, then there is an interval $(x_M-\epsilon_M, x_M+\epsilon_M)$ such that $|f(x)|>M$.
This means that:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)| > \sum_{M\in\mathbb{N}}2\epsilon_M M =\infty$$

but this depends on $\epsilon_M$ (so it is not necessarily $\infty$). How can I proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: $f$ need not be bounded. Just imagine a bunch of bumps which get higher and higher, but narrower and narrower, so $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ and in $L^1$, but not bounded.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Right, thanks! I still can't seem to relate this to the derivative though...

Comment: actually, the more I think of it, I feel like the statement itself is wrong. Again, imagine lots of bumps centered at integers (imagine a discontinuous function first for simplicity). If the bumps are say of width $\frac{1}{n^3}$ and height $n$, then this is in $L^1$ (since $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$), but not in $L^2$ (since $\sum\frac{1}{n}=\infty$). YOu can easily smooth this out, and introduce a small $\epsilon$ of error, and achieve the same result. (Edit: I see this is exactly what the answer below tells us)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This statement is incorrect. To make a counterexample, first define a non-negative $C^1$ function $f_0$ with support in $[-1,1]$, e.g. $f_0(x) = (1-x^2)^2$ for $|x| < 1$ and $f_0(x) = 0$ otherwise. Let $c_0 = \int_{-1}^1 f_0(x)dx$ and $c_1 = \int_{-1}^1 f_0^2(x) dx$. *Here, $c_0 = \frac{16}{15}$ and $c_1 = \frac{256}{315}$.*

Now set
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty n \cdot f_0(n^3(x-n))
$$
Then
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} f(x) dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{c_0}{n^2} < \infty
$$
but
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} f^2(x) dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{c_1}{n}
$$
does not converge.

The reason is that functions in $C^1 \cap L^1$ are **not** necessarily bounded.